# Find maximum of succession $a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2+n+4}{2n^2+1}a_n$ knowing $a_1=1$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to find out what's the maximum of the following sequence:

$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
a_1=1 \\ 
a_{n+1}=\frac{n^2+n+4}{2n^2+1}a_n \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

I know that the limit of $a_n$ is equal to $0$. I have no clue about how to find the maximum. I have tried to find out the values of $a_1, a_2, a_3\dots$ but we couldn't find the maximum. Please note that $n\geq 0$. Any hints?

Comment: There's something wrong here. The limit is obviously $\frac12$. Are you sure that you got the definition right?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yes, what we did was finding $lim {\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}}$ this gives $1/2$ which for the rule of division (not sure what's it called in English) gives that since $1/2 < 1$ the limit $\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: So, you are **sure** that the definition of $a_{n+1}$ does **not** use $a_n$.

Comment: It must be something wrong. Who cares about $a_1$ if $a_{n+1}$ is just a function of $n$ ?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sorry, edited the question. I forgot to put the $a_n$.

Comment: What are the values you computed for $a_1,a_2,a_3,\cdots$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows from your definition that $a_{n+1}>a_n$ is $n=1$ or $n=2$ and that $a_{n+1}<a_n$ otherwise. Therefore, the maximum is attained when $n=3$. That maximum is $\frac{20}9$, since $a_3=\frac{20}9$.

Comment: My textbook says that the extreme value of the function (maximum) is $\frac {20}{19}$.

Comment: @Cesare Since$$a_2=\frac{1^2+1+4}{2\times1^2+1}=\frac63=2>\frac{20}{19},$$that's trivially false.

Comment: @Winther I saw that. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: @Winther I used the correct sequence, but I made a computational mistake. You are right: the maximum is $\frac{20}9$. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Therefore $a_4$ should be less than $\frac {20}{9}$?

Comment: I think my professor wants us to show proof without calculations (perhaps using induction). Is this the only way to do this?

Comment: @Cesare At least, it was the only way that I was able to imagine.

Comment: @Cesare please not my answer, where i skip concrete calculations of $a_n$ and only focus on properties of you recursion ... or don't ;)

Answer (score 1):

In general for a recursion of the form:
$$
a_{n+1} = f(n)a_{n}, a_{1} > 0.
$$
if $f(n) - 1$ has only one zero $> 0$ and $lim_{n\to\infty}f(n) < 1$ then you know $a_{n}$ will attain its maximum for the largest $n$ for which you have $f(n)\geq 1$.

in this case:
$f(n)= \frac{n^2+n+4}{2n^2+1} > 1\Rightarrow - n^2 +n +3 > 0 \Rightarrow n < \frac{1+\sqrt{13}}{2} \approx 2.303$. Thus your maximum is $a_{3}$ ...